# How to uncheck other checkboxes or uncheck radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

In this particular case I'm working on I want a radio button behavior from my check boxes, with the only exception begin that you can uncheck the checkbox as well leaving nothing selected. As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to uncheck a radio button. I've been trying to come up with a simple code for normal check boxes that would uncheck others if one is enabled and leave all disabled if one is disabled. So far nothing I've tried has worked as intended, so I'm gonna have to ask if others know a simple way to code this. Preferably as a event for each check box if possible.

EDIT: Code

```
    private void checkLukitse1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        checkLukitse1.Checked = !checkLukitse1.Checked; // Invert state if clicked
        checkLukitse2.Checked = false; // Disable others
        checkLukitse3.Checked = false;
        checkLukitse4.Checked = false;
    }
```

EDIT 2: And of course something similar for other check boxes, but with different names for the checked states for each one

Comment: Which UI technology are you using ?

Comment: can you update the sample code in your Question

Comment: I we don't see your code, we cannot tell you why it does not work.

Comment: You may need to use a flag to discern user and code actions.

Comment: @Sham I'm using Windows Forms

Comment: IMO the question was easily understood without the code, and the code you posted shows what you want to accomplish. In my answer I give you a winforms derived control that makes radio buttons perform the way you want. You can do it without making a new control, but this way is much easier.  If you really want checkboxes to behave like radio buttons, that's also easy in a derived control. Also, there is a tag for winforms and if you use that tag you'll likely get better / faster answers.  Welcome to SO! Remember to upvote helpful answers and accept one if it solves your problem.

Comment: Using checkboxes instead of radiobuttons is a common GUI blooper.  Blooper #1 in the book, recommended reading btw.  Unchecking a radio button is possible, set its AutoCheck property to False.  You then do always have to implement its Click event.  Using a single event handler for all buttons gets the job done, the *sender* argument tells you which one was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To tidy up a little bit your code, you can write something like this:

```
 private void checkLukitse1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    UncheckEverything()
    checkLukitse1.Checked = true;
}
```

Of course, the UnckeckEverything() method should change the status of all the checkboxes to false, and then you can simply mark only one checkbox as checked. This way you'll get the radio button behaviour.

If you want to allow the "no option selected" case you can do that by adding a button to clear all the checkboxes (the click event will only call the UncheckEverything) or you can do something like:

```
private void checkLukitse1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var previousValue = checkLukitse1.Checked;
    UncheckEverything()
    checkLukitse1.Checked = !previousValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it is a bit difficult without your code.

However, I suggest making the change in the CheckedChanged event. I suspect that you are changing the other check boxes using the checked state of the box ***before*** it has actually changed.

You would check the current state, and then set the check boxes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `MouseCklick` event but the `CheckedChanged` event. Also, be aware of the fact that changing the `Checked` property does trigger the event again. Therefore I am setting the flag `_changing` when starting the un-checking procedure and exit the procedure if it set already, to prevent reentering the procedure.

Also, the whole thing becomes easier if we put all the check boxes in an array and if we attach the `CheckedChanged` event of all check boxes to one single event handler.

```
private CheckBox[] _checkBoxes;
private bool _changing;

public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _checkBoxes = new CheckBox[] {
        checkLukitse1, checkLukitse2, checkLukitse3, checkLukitse4
    };
}

// All check boxes attached to this event handler
private void checkLukitse_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var current = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (current.Checked && !_changing) {
        _changing = true;
        try {
            foreach (CheckBox other in _checkBoxes.Where(cb => cb != current)) {
                other.Checked = false;
            }
        } finally {
            _changing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also, that we don't have to do anything, if the user unchecked a combo box. Therefore the test `current.Checked`.

The `try-finally` ensures that the `_changing` flag will be reset under any circumstances. Even if an exception should occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make actual radio buttons behave the way you want, by making a derived control I'll call ClearableRadioButton, which inherits from RadioButton.

A ClearableRadioButton will select itself and unselect all others when first clicked, like an ordinary radio button. However, if you click it when it's already selected, it will simply turn itself off.

Just add this class to your project, build it once, and it will appear in your toolbox and can be used like any other control.

This example is for WinForms, but you can do the same thing in WPF. It compiles and works perfectly for me, exactly as written.

```
using System;

namespace test_radio_buttons
{
    class ClearableRadioButton : System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    {
        private bool _checkedChanged = false;
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
            if (_checkedChanged)
                _checkedChanged = false;
            else
                base.Checked = false;
        }
        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
            _checkedChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you dont *have* to use a derived control -- you could just do this in your form, but you would need to do it for all the radio buttons individually, or else chain their event handlers. It's easier to make a ClearableRadioButton once and just use it where you want it.

How it works: OnClick is fired when you click on a specific button. CheckedChanged is fired when the state of the button actually changes. CheckedChanged is fired BEFORE OnClick, so I simply need to set a flag true when CheckedChanged is called.

If OnClick is called and the flag is set, it means the radio button must have just been checked. In that case I just clear the flag.

If OnClick is called and the flag is NOT set, it means the button was clicked and didn't change state, which only happens when you click an already-checked button. In that case I just set button.Checked to false.